# Syntax error on if in Python

Tags: python

```
petname = ['Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Fat-tail'];\
  print ('what is your pets name?');\
  name = input();\
  if name not in petname:;\
```

i get syntax error for my code above? can someone please help

Comment: What is `if name not in petname:;` supposed to do?

Comment: i need to write a print statement after that. I get the error when i hit enter.the if statement is suppose to check if the name entered is not in the petname list

Comment: What are all those semicolons and backslashes for?

Comment: Python doesn't have statement/line terminators (`;`). Start with some tutorials, and get an IDE (PyScripter perhaps) or at least a text editor that has syntax highlighting.

Comment: ;\ is to move to a new line without executing the current line in IDLE

Comment: Well, you're now seeing the problems with your attempt to use ``;\`` as a general-purpose "don't-execute-yet" indicator.

Comment: It works now , i was trying to compile multiple statements at once. There was syntax error on else which was the indentation error.Figured out why it was doing. Thanks guys. Long way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it this way, if i am correct to assume this is your purpose:

```
petname = ['Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Fat-tail']
print ('What is your pets name?')
name = input()
if name not in petname:
    print ('Your pet is not in the list')
else:
    print ('Your pet is in the list')
```